# Change ImageView tint in an ImageView array

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I am trying to change multiple `ImageView` tint color contained in an array.

All 8 `ImageViews` have an id of block1,block2 .... to block8
And I use  block+i  with `findViewById` in a loop to refer to them.

```
    private ImageView arrowUp, arrowDown;
    private ImageView[] blocks = new ImageView[8];
    private TextView result;
    private static final String TAG = "TEST";

    private int jaugeValue = 0;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrowDown = findViewById(R.id.arrowDown);
        arrowUp = findViewById(R.id.arrowUp);
        result = findViewById(R.id.result);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { 
            int res = getResources().getIdentifier("block"+i, "id", getPackageName()); 
            blocks[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(res);
        }

        blocks[0].setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));


        arrowDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jaugeValue--;
                changeTextValue();
            }
        });

        arrowUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                jaugeValue++;
                changeTextValue();
            }
        });
    }

    private void changeTextValue(){
        String displayValue = Integer.toString(jaugeValue);
        if(jaugeValue < 0)
        {
            jaugeValue = 0;
            displayValue = Integer.toString(jaugeValue);
        }
        else if(jaugeValue > 8)
        {
            jaugeValue = 8;
            displayValue = Integer.toString(jaugeValue);

        }
        result.setText(displayValue);
    }
}
```

After that I try to set one of the `ImageView` tint color using :

```
blocks[0].setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
```

At this point I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setColorFilter(int)' on a null object reference
```

Any ideas on why this is causing a null reference ?

I can also confirm that my array is filled with `ImageViews` when printing in the log.

Comment: where you gave IDs to your ImageView?

Comment: Directly in the xml code of my main layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have change your for loop like below because you are started for loop with 0 but there are **no id of block0** So,it's gave error.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { 
    int res = getResources().getIdentifier("block"+(i+1), "id", getPackageName()); 
    blocks[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(res);
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Thank you!! That was such a newbie mistake.. I kept the same loop but renamed them from 0 to 7. My first image had an id of block1 so I was actually refering from block0 which didn't exist.

Comment: @AshwiniViolet He is define id as block1,block2 .... to block8 and get id using "block"+i So, for i=o it's give block0 id which are not define by him.

Comment: Loop is wrong  but he did point out my mistake should I mark it as resolved ?